# Set two styles for a single cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How can I set two different styles for a single cell? Currently  I am showing a cell value in

1. **BOLD**
2. currency format eg: `2,300`.

expected o/p: **`2,300`**

But the last style overrides the earlier one, and i can only  the later property.

```
XSSFCellStyle my_style = (XSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
    XSSFFont my_font=(XSSFFont) wb.createFont();
    my_font.setBoldweight(XSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    my_style.setFont(my_font);
XSSFCellStyle currencyFormat = (XSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
    XSSFDataFormat df =(XSSFDataFormat) wb.createDataFormat(); 
    currencyFormat.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("#,##0"));
```

setting the data here

```
                rowSavingsTotal.createCell(a).setCellValue(2300); 
                rowSavingsTotal.getCell(a).setCellStyle(my_style);
                rowSavingsTotal.getCell(a).setCellStyle(currencyFormat);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only put one style on a cell. Just merge the two of them :

```
XSSFCellStyle my_style = (XSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
XSSFFont my_font=(XSSFFont) wb.createFont();
my_font.setBoldweight(XSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
my_style.setFont(my_font);
XSSFDataFormat df =(XSSFDataFormat) wb.createDataFormat(); 
my_style.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("#,##0"));
```

---

```
rowSavingsTotal.createCell(a).setCellValue(2300); 
rowSavingsTotal.getCell(a).setCellStyle(my_style);
```

Comment: Thanks for the  quick reply. It worked!! . But there are also some cases where I want to show the value only in currency format but not bold.

Comment: You can create a CurrencyFormat style, and use for special cases the `cloneStyleFrom(CellStyle source)` method. Then on the cloned style you can apply `BOLD`.